# How to do operations inside pandas dataframe based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this pandas dataframe:

[image: dataframe i have]

I want that

IF there is a day that a row of condition_2 is 'True' BEFORE a row of condition_1,
then, change the row of condition_2 to NaN.

Dataframe structure:
There is not the possibility to have True and True in the same row of the columns

So in the previous dataframe, this is what should look like:

[image: dataframe i want to have]

This is sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
tbl = {"date" :["2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-27", "2022-02-28", "2022-02-28","2022-02-28"],
        "condition_1" : ["True", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "True", "NaN"],
        "condition_2" : ["NaN", "NaN", "True", "True", "NaN", "NaN"]}



df = pd.DataFrame(tbl)
df = df.replace('NaN', float('nan'))
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df.sort_values(by = "date", inplace=True)
```

Any ideas? Maybe I can use a for loop and if conditions?

Comment: Please [don't use images for text data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11659881).

Comment: Ok, what can I use?

Comment: You can simply print the dataframe and then format it as code

Comment: What if the `True` of `condition_2` in day 02-27 is in the middle line?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh It's ok, no problem. It remains 'True'

Comment: What remains True? True in 02-28?

Comment: No, the 02-28 is another day. The previous day (in this case, 02-27) has no influence to the next day(02-28). They are uncorrelated. If the 'True' is in the middle line considering 02-27, so this value remain True) The problem is when the 'True' of condition_2  is before the 'True' of condition_1 considering the same DAY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby `date` column and compare the `condition` by shift

```py
m = (df.groupby('date', as_index=False, group_keys=False)
     .apply(lambda g: g['condition_2'].eq('True') & g['condition_1'].shift(-1).eq('True')))

df['condition_2'] = df['condition_2'].mask(m, 'NaN')
```

```
print(m)

0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool

print(df)

         date condition_1 condition_2
0  2022-02-27        True         NaN
1  2022-02-27         NaN         NaN
2  2022-02-27         NaN        True
3  2022-02-28         NaN         NaN
4  2022-02-28        True         NaN
5  2022-02-28         NaN         NaN
```